# Sending GeoJSON from Cybertracker to Django Rest Framework - cannot decode

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I am sending a GeoJSON object from Cybertracker app to my Djanog Rest Framework API.

This is how the data looks coming into my server:

```
 if request.method == "POST":
    print request.body

    >> { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [0.000000, 0.000000] },
      "properties": {
        "deviceId": "00000000-7678-5656-0732-23e40033c587",
        "id": "185e0c80-9d29-1314-9b8c-167bd853aab8",
        "dateTime": "Not implemented",
        "sighting": {
          "species": "White rhino",
          "count": 2,
          "activity": "Standing in shade",
          "temp": 34
        }
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [0.000000, 0.000000] },
      "properties": {
        "deviceId": "00000000-7678-5656-0732-23e40033c587",
        "id": "74ca6c6c-6a1d-4410-b816-fe34a2c95f66",
        "dateTime": "Not implemented",
        "sighting": {
          "species": "Black rhino",
          "count": 1,
          "activity": "Feeding",
          "temp": 28
        }
      }
    }
    ]}
```

I try and parse the data but same problems:

```
print json.loads(request.body)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 30 column 3 - line 30 column 4 (char 843 - 844)

print JSONParser().parse(request)
File "/Users/hermanstander/apps/afriapps/rhino_monitoring/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/parsers.py", line 68, in parse
    raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))
ParseError: JSON parse error - Extra data: line 30 column 3 - line 30 column 4 (char 843 - 844)
```

Comment: I just did the same thing in my shell and it worked fine. It seems there is something else in `request.body`.

Comment: I think your right, I just dont know whats wrong there

Comment: Could you check the length of `request.body` to see if there are any extra chars than you need?

Comment: print len(request.body) : I checked, its 844 charachters

Comment: The error seems to be occurring in the last two chars. You can check what are those chars.